# how to call a method when mat-option is selected (angular)?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, binding, angular-material

I am new to Angular and I want to call a specific method, only when option3 is selected.
I am struggling to solve this and cannot find much information on this on the internet.

When I call option3, the output is empty.

Here is my code so far:

app.component.html:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected" >
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
    <mat-option selectionChange="greet($event)">Option 3</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<p>You selected: {{selected}}</p>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'materialdesign';
  selected = 'option33';


  greet() {
    this.selected = 'it works';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to listen to an event from an Angular component, you need to add parenthesis around the event:

```
<mat-option (selectionChange)="greet($event)">Option 3</mat-option>
```

Then your should method should start executing.

Comment: Thank you, this also works. There is just a little bug: when I click on option3, the output will be right, but the selection box doesn't show Option 3 anymore. It's just empty. Do you know how to solve it? Its still there, even when I add a value to the mat-option

Comment: Looks like others have stated when you change the value of `this.selected` to bind to a value that does not match a `mat-option` you'll move into a deselected state because `selected` is bound to the `value` of the `mat-select`.

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected" (selectionChange)="inputChange()">
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<p>You selected: {{selected}}</p>
```

in component.ts

```
title = 'materialdesign';
  selected = 'option33';
inputChange(){
  if(this.selected == 'option3'){
    this.greet();
  }
}

  greet() {
    this.selected = 'it works';
  }
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tbef9f?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.ts)

Comment: Thank you, this also works. There is just a little bug: when I click on option3, the output will be right, but the selection box doesn't show Option 3 anymore. It's just empty. Do you know how to solve it? Its still there, even when I add a value to the mat-option

Answer (score 0):

Try like below,

selectionChange event is part of mat-select. So Just call the method when you select an option from the list. And based on the value of the option selected, execute your required code.

**.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected" (selectionChange)="greet($event)">
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**.ts**

```
selected: string;

greet(event) {
  if(event.value === 'option3') {
    // Execute the required code
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. There is just a little bug: when I click on option3, the output will be right, but the selection box doesn't show Option 3 anymore. It's just empty. Do you know why its the case?

Comment: You forgot to keep value attribute for the option3 mat-option.

<mat-option selectionChange="greet($event)">Option 3</mat-option>

Comment: Now I am irritated. Should I change the last mat-option aswell? Could you maybe edit your answer?

Comment: Yes. Replace the last option with <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>

Comment: I did it, but the bug is still there. When I click on option3, right output is there but Option3 is not shown anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define `click` event handler on the specific `mat-option` element.

```
<mat-option value="option3" (click)="greet()">Option 3</mat-option>
```

Comment: Thank you, this also works. There is just a little bug: when I click on option3, the output will be right, but the selection box doesn't show Option 3 anymore. It's just empty. Do you know how to solve it? Its still there, even when I add a value to the mat-option

Comment: That's because inside `greet` method, you overwrite `this.selected` with a value that doesn't correspond to any `mat-option`.

Comment: Oh, yeah that makes sense. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Remove `this.selected = 'it works';` from `greet` method. The property `this.selected` is already automatically updated due to the two-way binding `[(value)]="selected"` on `mat-select`.